# Collection with Attributes or Specified With()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I've got the following relationship and attribute in my model `Donation` -

```
public function donationUpdates(){
        return $this->hasMany(donationUpdate::class,'donationID');
    }

    public function getdonationUploadStatusAttribute(){
        $donationUploadStatus = $this->donationUpdates()->where([
            ['actionCategoryID', 1],
            ['actionID', 2]
        ])->orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();
        return $donationUploadStatus ;
    }
```

At the moment, I'm trying to expand and correct a project created by my predecessor and they had the following query which would be returned later in the function to json for use in an ajax script:

```
   $donationsOpen = Donation::with('donationUpdates')
        ->where('donorID', $customer->id)
        ->whereNotIn('hold_status', [2,3])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->get();
```

Now, at the moment this works okay, but the problem is as there are a multitude of `donationUpdates` with each donation, it returns a `collection` itself.

I was curious if there was a way for me to either access the `getdonationUploadStatusAttribute` with each item or if I could go through the `donationUpdates` and filter out to the first one like I normally would do through the model attibute.

I'd appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `HasOne` relationship:

```php
public function donationUploadStatus(){
    return $this->hasOne(donationUpdate::class,'donationID')
        ->where([
            ['actionCategoryID', 1],
            ['actionID', 2]
        ])->orderBy('created_at','desc');
}

$donationsOpen = Donation::with('donationUploadStatus')
    ->where('donorID', $customer->id)
    ->whereNotIn('hold_status', [2,3])
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a query to your `with` like so:

```
 $donationsOpen = Donation::with(['donationUpdates', function($query){
        $query->where([
            ['actionCategoryID', 1],
            ['actionID', 2]
        ]);
    }])
    ->where('donorID', $customer->id)
    ->whereNotIn('hold_status', [2,3])
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```

The function in the `with` will query only the donationUpdates and filter those out.